# Errors while installing Android Studio packages using PPA

Tags: package-management, software-installation, ppa, android-studio

I'm trying to install the Android Studio packages using a PPA with these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
sudo apt-get update
```

But I keep getting these errors:

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/paolorotolo/android-studio/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/paolorotolo/android-studio/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found<br>
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

As a result, the Android Studio isn't working either. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: There are no packages for `zesty` in this PPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pilot6 is correct, there's no packages for Ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty Zapus) in that PPA. You can, however, point your PPA to the packages for the Ubuntu 16.04 or 16.10 releases and get the packages that way. To do that, hit <kbd>Super</kbd>, type 'Software & Updates', press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Click on the 'Other Software' tab, then click on the PPA, then 'Edit...'. Change 'Distribution:' to 'yakkety' or 'xenial' (both without quotes).

However, this is not really the way you want to be getting Android Studio, that PPA looks out-of-date. You have two options for installing Android Studio (sadly I'm not aware of a snap of Android Studio yet).

### Use Ubuntu's tool - Ubuntu Make

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-make
umake android
```

This seems the easier way to install Android Studio.

### Install manually

1. [Download Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#linux-bundle)
2. If running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, run `sudo add-apt-architecture i386 ; sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386`
3. Unpack the .zip file you downloaded to an appropriate location for your applications, such as within /usr/local/ for your user profile, or /opt/ for shared users.
4. To launch Android Studio, open a terminal, navigate to the android-studio/bin/ directory, and execute studio.sh.
5. Select whether you want to import previous Android Studio settings or not, then click OK.
6. The Android Studio Setup Wizard guides you though the rest of the setup, which includes downloading Android SDK components that are required for development.
7. To make Android Studio available in your list of applications, select Tools > Create Desktop Entry from the Android Studio menu bar.

<sub>[Source for Ubuntu Make install instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make)

[Source for the manual install](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html) (click 'Linux' under 'Instructions for')</sub>